# "The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here is my code
I tried removing the public but it just shows more errors
It shows The modifier public/private is not valid for this item

```
    public string GetPlayerSide();
    {
    return "?";

    }

    public void EndTurn();
{
    Debug.Log("EndTurn is not implemented!");
}
 
}
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you included all the code (or at least the containing scope). Your code is obviously wrong (with a semi-colon and then a code block), but without context we really can't tell. If it's in a class, then the semi-colons should be removed. If it's in an interface, then both the `public` and the block should be removed. If it's a *local function*, then the public and the semi-colon should go

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove ';'

Incorrect version:

```
public void EndTurn();
```

Correct version:

```
public void EndTurn()
```

Complete code:

```
    public string GetPlayerSide()
    {
        return "?";

    }

    public void EndTurn()
    {
        Debug.Log("EndTurn is not implemented!");
    }
```

Comment: The opposite of correct is *incorrect*, not false ;)